# Wordpress child theme CSS path

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm just getting started on Wordpress and although I was making decent progress tweaking my `html5blank` theme. Everyone kept telling me I should be using a child theme instead - so I decided to do so!

I still want to keep my css/font/js/img folders as close as I can to the structure in original HTML templates. Before using a child theme, I used to load in my `/css/main.css` file in `.header.php` like this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/main.css">`

Now I understand I should load it in the `html5blank-child` folder in `.functions.php` like this:

```
<?php   
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
        function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/main.css' );
    }
?>
```

This *seemed* to work but obviously the styles from `html5blank/style.css` are inherited. I’m guessing it’s not a good idea to remove the file? What would be the best way to handle this?

One other issue with this is I can access the admin via the `/wp-admin` URL but if I go to a post and 'update' it it goes to a blank `post.php` page

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using

```
get_template_directory_uri()
```

use

```
get_stylesheet_directory_uri()
```

and you will always get files from your child theme, if file is not found in child theme it will fallback to your parent theme.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply, I've tried both of the snippets of code above but neither calls my stylesheet. The path I used was `/css/main.css`. The original style.css is still used from the parent. Could this be because of how the parent theme works? It's a 'blank' theme, so maybe it's meant to be edited directly and not child-theme friendly?